# How to save the welllog data in time domain in ocean

Tags: ocean, petrel

Output of my plug-in is welllog in time domain. So I want to create welllog with time domain in ocean. so how can I do that???? or if this is not possible Is it possible to change the domain of wellog from time to depth without using velocity model (I can use seismic data whole along the welllog trajectory)

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, WellLogSample only deals with MD to "position" the samples.  Logs are never explicitly positioned in time - the borehole may be.
Assuming that your borehole has a time-depth-relationship (TDR), you can use something like this:

```
Dictionary<double,double> timeValues = ...; // (TWT,value) pairs
Borehole bh = ...;
WellLog log = ...;
using (ITransaction trans = DataManager.NewTransaction())
{
  trans.Lock(log);
  log.Samples = timeValues
    .Select(tv => new WellLogSample(bh.Transform(Domain.TWT, tv.Key, Domain.MD), tv.Value))
    .Where(s => !double.IsNaN(s.MD))
    .OrderBy(s => s.MD);
  trans.Commit();
}
```